# Two HC05 Bluetooth Bind problem

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I succeeded in giving an AT command. My two BL MAC addresses are `21, 13, A03B` and `21, 13, A3E2`.

When I want to connect one to the other I use `AT+BIND=21,13,A3E2`. But then I see `Error(7)`. If I use another BL address from the Internet, it works.

So, why won't my 2 HC05 bind?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
AT+BIND=0021,13,00A03B
```

NB: Here I just added `00` left side and right side digits

Answer (score -1):

I think that this is an error caused by a difference of firmware versions. Now BT is on version 3.0-20170601 and I think that this version does not accept these `link` or `bind` commands.